# euro hinge installation too far

Tags: doors, cabinets, door-frame, hinges

I decided to replace the hinges on my doors recently. Unfortunately, I drilled the holes in the door a bit too far from the edge and when I try to open the door it hits the frame.

It seems to me I need a slightly longer "neck" on the hinge to open. Is there such a product? Also, where would you recommend purchasing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fill in the holes with broken-off toothpicks and wood glue, then drill new holes a little farther away and re-install the hinges.

Answer (score 2):

Providing a reference or image to your hinge would be helpful.  However, typically they are adjustable by loosening the screw that holds the two parts together and sliding it apart slightly, then re-tightening the screw.

[image: Hinge]
<sub>(source: [handymanknowhow.co.uk](http://www.handymanknowhow.co.uk/repairs/hingeondoor463witharrowstext%20copy.jpgdoor.jpg))</sub>

It sounds like in you case you'd want to loosen screw C and then pull A away from the plate secured with screw B.

Comment: In my case I've already adjusted it to the maximum. It was creating a large gap between the frame and the door and it still wasn't far enough. I ended up drilling new holes instead right below using a jig I made. Worked out pretty well.